# How do I figure out how to run a program installed through pacman?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, package-management, pacman

It happened to me multiple times, that I installed a package, but did not now the exact command how to run it, if it was not the same as the package name.

Lately I installed `gnome-bluetooth`, a bluetooth manager with the gnome GUI. But the command `gnome-bluetooth` won't run it. How can I look up the command to execute the installed program?

Comment: `pacman -Ql gnome-bluetooth` will list the files installed by that package.

Answer (score 0):

A Quick lookup through documentation gives this:
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-bluetooth/stable/gnome-bluetooth-applet.html.en

If not mentioned here , file a bug report/IRC channels will help you if this is not in documentation and resolve with link.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking there is a hint or short description somewhere in the pacman package.